# How to persist the egress messages of Aeron cluster

Tags: aeron

My Aeron cluster clients share an identical output stream, and I want to be able to persist it for playback at a later time.
Can anyone offer some ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can setup a recording for an egress stream. One way would be to ensure your egress has a monotonic correlation id, and/or track the published position, for the egress and setup the recording once that position, or correlation id, has been reached when recovering. The existing position of the recording can be queried on service start.